# Where did they end up flying to and living at the end of Mad Max Beyond Thunderdome?

Tags: mad-max

They fly over a wrecked city, but they don't show where they land and start living. Do they live in that city or fly on to some other location? If so, where?

Comment: They appear to end up living in the ruined city; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJ1KZvzXpKI

Comment: They flew _beyond the Thunderdome_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are seen living in the city at the end of the movie. They have lit lanterns and fires in the ruins to create all the city lights from their stories of Tomorrow-morrow land, and as the narrator says, to guide Max there.

The city is Sydney, there are a few famous landmarks shown including a broken part of the Sydney Harbour Bridge and the Opera House.

A picture of the city lit up in the end shows the bridge in the background:
[image]

Footage of the models used can bee seen [here](http://www.madmaxmovies.com/mad-max-beyond-thunderdome/filming-locations/sydneyscape-model-set/index.html).